# STOPWATCH for a column

Tags: sql-server, timer, stopwatch

In our organization helpdesk, we would like to calculate the time spent from the time the ticket is created. We have many locations, with different operational hours settings. Some locations will work 24x7 and some will work from 9AM to 5 PM. Every morning, I need to run a query to get the tickets with age more than 8 hrs and perform some action on it. Is there stopwatch column in SQL Server or any other option, by which the age gets incremented in minutes automatically, so that whenever we query, we can get the exact age since creation.

For eg., If the location is branch office and a ticket created at 2020/07/10 15:00 PM, and If query is executed on t 2020/07/11 09:00 AM, the age as per operational hours (9 AM to 5 PM) is 2 hrs. If the location of the ticket is head office, then operational hours is 24x7 and age of the ticket as per operational hours would be 18 hrs.

Added 3 columns for processing this information..

IS_TIMER_RUNNING : true | false true: when  in operational hours (9 AM - 5 PM). false: outside operational hours (5 PM - 9 AM).
TIMER_RUNNING_TIME : datetime
TICKET_AGE : time in seconds

Using job at 9 AM , the IS_TIMER_RUNNING will be set to true. At 5 PM job,IS_TIMER_RUNNING will be set to false and  TICKET_AGE will be populated with time in seconds until end of that time.

I tried the following query which gives expected query.

```
SELECT 
  TICKETID, 
  CONVERT(
    VARCHAR, 
    DATEADD(
      s, 
      CASE WHEN IS_TIMER_RUNNING = '1' THEN datediff(
        s, 
        dateadd(
          s, 
          (wo.TIMER_RUNNING_TIME / 1000), 
          '1970-01-01 00:00:00'
        ), 
        GETUTCDATE()
      ) + TICKET_AGE ELSE TICKET_AGE END, 
      '1900/01/01'
    ), 
    108
  ) 
FROM 
  TICKET
```

Kindly suggest if any other better option is available

Comment: You query using a datediff function to calculate the age... you don't need the column to store it.

Comment: Quoting @DaleK , just use a datediff(creation_date, now())

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply . For eg., If the location is branch office and a ticket created at 2020/07/10 15:00 PM, and If query is executed on t 2020/07/11 09:00 AM, the age as per operational hours (9 AM to 5 PM) is 2 hrs. Could you please confirm whether this is possible with datediff.

Comment: If you add some sample data (ideally as DDL/DML), expected results, and an attempt at a query someone will help you get it working. ([edit] into the question - not as a comment).

Comment: And take a look at the official docs for datediff.

Comment: Hi @user2007289 
As others have mentioned, have a look at the documentation. There are some great examples. Not sure which version of SQL Server you are on...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: By sample data and expected results, we need tabular data (formatted text not images) - in addition to the text description.

Comment: To answer your actual question - no, there is no built-in functionality. And you will struggle to write code to do this if the calculation requires knowledge of working hours based on location (and perhaps even based on the persons assigned). And beware of DST changing during the time a ticket is open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a table with all the business hours (taking weekends,holidays and different work schedules) into account.
After that you join this table with working hours to your ticket (taking into account the applicable schedule) and then use `DATEDIFF` to calculate the time elapsed.

e.g. creating a "business hours table"

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;

WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT cast('2020-01-01' as datetime) as theDate
UNION ALL
SELECT dateadd(day,1,theDate)
FROM CTE
WHERE theDate<='2020-12-31'
)
SELECT 1 as BusinessHoursId,DateAdd(hh,9,theDate) as SOB,DATEADD(hh,17,theDate) as EOB
into Businesshours
FROM CTE
WHERE DATEPART(DW,theDate) between 1 and 5
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Then you can use this table in a join:

```
SELECT TicketId,
       SUM(DATEDIFF(n,
               CASE WHEN t.Created > bh.SOB THEN t.Created ELSE bh.SOB END ,
               CASE WHEN t.Closed < bh.EOB THEN t.Closed ELSE bh.EOB END
               )
          )
         
FROM Tickets t
JOIN Businesshours bh
ON t.Created < bh.EOB
AND t.Closed > bh.SOB
GROUP BY TicketId
```